# Bug implementing Stopwatch in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

```
  Widget decibelsIcons(){
    final stopwatch = Stopwatch();

    if (!_isRecording) {
      stopwatch.reset();
      return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.waveform, size: 80, color: Colors.blue);
    } else{
      if (maxDB != null && maxDB !>= 70 && maxDB !<= 80) {
        stopwatch.reset();
        return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.speaker_1_fill, size: 80, color: Colors.green);
      } else if (maxDB != null && maxDB !>= 70 && maxDB !<= 80) { 
        stopwatch.reset();
        return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.speaker_1_fill, size: 80, color: Colors.green);
      } else if (maxDB != null && maxDB !>= 80 && maxDB !<= 87) {
        stopwatch.reset();
        return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.speaker_2_fill, size: 80, color: Colors.green);
      } else if  (maxDB != null && maxDB !>= 88) {
        stopwatch.reset();
        return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.volume_up, 
                            size: 80, 
                            color: Colors.red);
      } else {
        final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start;
        while (stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds < 1){
          return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.speaker_1_fill, size: 80, color: Colors.yellow);

        }
        return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.volume_mute, size: 80, color: Colors.red);
      }
                      
    }                 
  }
```

I am unable to seem the bug in the code. I am measuring the decibel level. I am implementing a stopwatch to have into consideration the natural pauses one makes while speaking.

Comment: Please describe the symptoms of the bug you're encountering.

Comment: When I am running the code the icon that is supposed to be displayed after 1 second won't run. This part -> "return const Icon(CupertinoIcons.volume_mute, size: 80, color: Colors.red);" The idea is that after one second of silence the icon should be displayed.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong: 1. You have duplicate cases for `maxDB! >= 70 && maxDB! <= 80`. 2. Your say you want to do something for 1 second, but your code checks for 1 *milli*second.  3. Your `Stopwatch` isn't actually doing anything.  You start it, immediately check `stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds < 1` (which probably will be true), and then immediately return the `speaker_1_fill` icon, exiting the `while` loop.  4. If your goal is to show the `speaker_1_fill` icon for 1 second and to then show the `volume_mute` icon, using a loop would be the wrong approach anyway.